# Why Flutter's AnimationController works only if screen is active?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have screen `A` and screen `B`. For example, on screen `A`, I have an `AnimationController` object that animates the toast(`OverlayEntry`):

```dart
class AViewState extends State<AView> {
  late OverlayState _overlay;
  late AnimationController _toastAnimationController;

  void _showToast() {
    final toast = OverlayEntry(...);

    _toastAnimationController.addListener(() {
      _overlay.setState({});
    });

    _overlay.insert(toast);
    _toastAnimationController.forward();

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      controller.reverse().whenComplete(() {
        _toastAnimationController.remove();
       });
    });
  }

  void _goB() {
    context.push("/b");
  }
}
```

This code works well. Until I go to another screen. If I try to open the `B` screen while the toast appears, it won't disappear until I return to the `A` screen. The `delayed` function executes, but `reverse` waits for me to return to screen `A`.

What is the reason for this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? Are there ways to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can give you an implementation that works, but I'm not familiar enough with the framework to answer the why part of this question. Let me know if you want the former.

Comment: @offworldwelcome thank you so much. I've found the reason. Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two days later I found the reason - it's because of the `TickerProvider`. If I use the `TickerProvider` of the page, it stops ticking while the screen is not active. So I solved it by moving the toasts logic to the very top level of my app(very root widget), because that widget is always active.